# add event to calendar IOS7 with my app

Tags: objective-c, calendar

i'm trying to build an app that would add events to the default calendar in IOS 7.
First i added a framework: EventKit.Framework and imported it in my .m

this is my code:

```
    - (void)AddEventToCalendar
{

    EKEventStore *eventStore = [[EKEventStore alloc] init];

    EKEvent *event = [EKEvent eventWithEventStore:eventStore];

    // title of the event
    event.title = @"Event";

    // star tomorrow
    event.startDate = [[NSDate date] dateByAddingTimeInterval:86400]; 

    // duration = 1 h
    event.endDate = [[NSDate date] dateByAddingTimeInterval:90000]; 

    // set the calendar of the event. - here default calendar
    [event setCalendar:[eventStore defaultCalendarForNewEvents]];

    // store the event
    NSError *err;
    [eventStore saveEvent:event span:EKSpanThisEvent error:&err];
}
```

but it gives me this error when i run this on my iPhone

> Error Domain=EKCADErrorDomain Code=1013 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (EKCADErrorDomain error 1013.)"

do you know what can i do?

Answer (score 4):

First of all, you must initialize your EventStore and then request access to use the user’s Calendar database with the following method:

```
[yourEventStore requestAccessToEntityType:EKEntityTypeEvent completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) {
    if(granted) {
        // create/edit your event here
}];
```

See the [AppleDocumentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/EventKitProgGuide/ReadingAndWritingEvents.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004775-SW1)

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 3):

try using ***requestAccessToEntity*** it will resolve your problem.